# Why am I getting these "WARNING: Target Directory <directory> already exists." when I pip install a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Here's an example, I just installed pyimgur to show what's going on.

```
C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\programming\python\books\automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python>python -m pip install pyimgur
Collecting pyimgur
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/8b/99df63567b53d5fa040f0048160fa0aa327b478821c2d8660841f6d45bea/pyimgur-0.6.0.tar.gz
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/40/a9837291310ee1ccc242ceb6ebfd9eb21539649f193a7c8c86ba15b98539/urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/63/df50cac98ea0d5b006c55a399c3bf1db9da7b5a24de7890bc9cfd5dd9e99/certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: idna, chardet, urllib3, certifi, requests, pyimgur
    Running setup.py install for pyimgur ... done
Successfully installed certifi-2019.11.28 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 pyimgur-0.6.0 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.7
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\certifi already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\certifi-2019.11.28.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\chardet already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\chardet-3.0.4.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\idna already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\idna-2.8.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\requests already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\requests-2.22.0.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\urllib3 already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\urllib3-1.25.7.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\MYSTERY_PERSON3000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\bin already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
```

Also when I reinstall modules that are already installed it prints out similar warnings instead of saying the module is already installed.

Comment: Are you using any sort of virtual environment (or similar)?

Comment: Nope, this is in windows command prompt.

Comment: I don’t use windows, but AFAIK the use of the command prompt has no effect on virtual environments, no?

Comment: Nope. What I was saying is that I was running this in the regular shell, no venv.

Comment: Oh, is there any particular reason for that? Does it work in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 3):

It says you have already installed that packages. Then why need to worry but if you want to install packages again and again try this command.

```
pip3 install [package_name] --upgrade
```